# How to write a function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Ok, so this is really dumb, but I don't understand how to write functions in Haskell that are outside of the main do area. I have this script that reads a file, finds the locations of a word in that file, and then bins the results into bins of 10:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Data.Text as T
import Data.Text.Internal.Search
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.Text.IO as TIO
import Statistics.Sample.Histogram

main :: IO ()
main = do
  rawText <- TIO.readFile "jane-eyre.asciidoc"
  let locations = indices "morning" rawText
      vec =  V.fromList $ Prelude.map fromIntegral locations
      (_, sizes) = histogram 10 vec
      histSizes = V.toList sizes
  print histSizes
```

This works fine. But now when I try to abstract some things into functions I can't. I try to put the first `rawText` into its own function, for instance:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Data.Text as T
import Data.Text.Internal.Search
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.Text.IO as TIO
import Statistics.Sample.Histogram

rawText = TIO.readFile "jane-eyre.asciidoc"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let locations = indices "morning" rawText
      vec =  V.fromList $ Prelude.map fromIntegral locations
      (_, sizes) = histogram 10 vec
      histSizes = V.toList sizes
  print histSizes
```

And I get:

```
 • Couldn't match expected type ‘Text’ with actual type ‘IO Text’
 • In the second argument of ‘indices’, namely ‘rawText’
```

Here's another example of something I tried:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Data.Text as T
import Data.Text.Internal.Search
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.Text.IO as TIO
import Statistics.Sample.Histogram

hist text = V.toList sizes where
  locations = indices "morning" text
  vec =  V.fromList $ Prelude.map fromIntegral locations
  (_, sizes) = histogram 10 vec

main :: IO ()
main = do
  rawText <- TIO.readFile "jane-eyre.asciidoc"
  histSizes <- hist rawText
  print histSizes
```

But I get:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘IO’
  Expected type: IO Integer
    Actual type: [Integer]
• In a stmt of a 'do' block: histSizes <- hist rawText
  In the expression:
    do { rawText <- TIO.readFile "jane-eyre.asciidoc";
         histSizes <- hist rawText;
         print histSizes }
  In an equation for ‘main’:
      main
        = do { rawText <- TIO.readFile "jane-eyre.asciidoc";
               histSizes <- hist rawText;
               print histSizes }
```

Comment: Please, use more specific question titles, since this one is overly general.

Comment: I would start slower and work through a good haskell book. Especially if those error messages don't mean anything to you, which seems to be the case.

Comment: rawText isn't a function

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To answer the title question “how to write a function”: well – *you just put it in your file*.

...but that's clearly not what you're trying to ask here. Thing is, `rawText` is not at all a function. In your working program, it's just a text value. And, as it depends on external data, it's not really a constant, it's actually a *variable*. Global variables are a bad idea (in all programming languages), so I do not see why you want to put that in global scope.

What you could do, however, is put the action that's used to *retrieve* the text in the module scope:

```
fetchRawText :: IO Text
fetchRawText = TIO.readFile "jane-eyre.asciidoc"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  rawText <- fetchRawText
  let locations = indices "morning" rawText
      vec =  V.fromList $ Prelude.map fromIntegral locations
      (_, sizes) = histogram 10 vec
      histSizes = V.toList sizes
  print histSizes
```

`fetchRawText` is now what other languages might call a “function with no arguments”, like

```py
def fetchRawText():
    return open("jane-eyre.asciidoc").read()
```

...except Haskell doesn't have *functions without arguments* (those are just values), it instead expresses the fact that there's a side-effect involved in fetching the value by having it in the `IO` monad.

A probably more sensible factoring of the program would however be this:

```
locationHistogramSizes :: Text -> [Double]
locationHistogramSizes rawText = V.toList sizes
 where locations = indices "morning" rawText
       vec =  V.fromList $ Prelude.map fromIntegral locations
       (_, sizes) = histogram 10 vec

main :: IO ()
main = do
   rawText <- TIO.readFile "jane-eyre.asciidoc"
   print $ locationHistogramSizes rawText
```

Here, I've completely seperated all of the interesting logic from the IO part. That, amongst other advantages, makes unit testing much easier.

Comment: More to the point, it's not that it's a bad idea, it's that you *can't*.

Answer (score 5):

Even though you've pulled it out of the `main`, `rawText` is still an impure value, yet you're trying to use it in a pure context. You'll still need to get it out of the Monad before you can use it:

```
main = do
  raw <- rawValue 
  let locations = indices "morning" raw
```

This may have been more obvious if you had tried giving it a signature (giving things explicit signatures is almost always a good idea). Had you written:

```
rawText :: Text
rawText = TIO.readFile "jane-eyre.asciidoc"
```

It would have told you that the signature was incorrect, which would have narrowed the problem down.

Because the code is so simple, taking it out doesn't lead to much in the way of gains. You'd be better off taking what all you have in the `main` right now, and making all of that its own function; if it makes conceptual sense.

Answer (score 2):

The bind `<-` syntax is not a normal assignment. It desugars to a monadic bind. `indices` can't take a value that's inside the `IO` monad. Any of the `let` bindings can be abstracted into functions very easily, as they're essentially renames. However, the `TIO.readFile` line has to be bound inside the `do` notation. Try abstracting the `let` bindings into functions for practice. But as a beginner, it's helpful to treat `do` notation and `<-` bindings as something magical and worry about what they actually mean once you understand monads later on.